# Are there any difference in passing parameters to another page using pagereference.getparameter and manually generating querystring

Tags: apex, visualforce

The 2 ways of passing parameters to another page  that i know of are

1. Use the pageReference class and use its getParameter method to assign parameters

   ```
   pageReference pr = Page.page1;
   pr.getParameters().put('param1',param);
   ```
2. Build a url using string and pass it to pagereference class

   ```
   String url = '/apex/page1?param1=param 
   pr = new PageReference(url);pr.setRedirect(true);
   ```

Are there anyother way we can pass params? What are differences in terms of best practice or performance or security

Or are they just the same?

Comment: If you hand-craft the URL it's your job to do the url encoding for one thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're the same, you will see any parameters added via addParameters in the URL as query parameters.

A more secure way to do it would be sharing a controller across Visualforce pages, in which case you wouldn't need to pass parameters between pages. However for this, I believe redirect needs to be false, or else it [flushes the ViewState](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm).

Comment: What you say at the end is correct.

Comment: Agree, I think the whole passing of view state topic needs more calling out in the docs. So many people resort to URL params because its not that well know. If the page standard controller and/or extensions are compatibile the view state will be shared, otherwise regardless of the redirect parameter, the state will not be shared.